# Qual significado do simbolo || '-' || no SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, string, oracle

Estou realizando uma consulta em um banco de dados Oracle e me deparo com esta simbologia  `|| '-' ||`, na minha *query*. Qual o significado?

```
Select
  xf0cdloc || '-' ||  XN4CDEMP AS LOCOMOTIVA,
From
  Trem
```

Comment: Pode colocar pelo menos toda a expressão que tem isso? OU a *query* toda. Desta forma, está incompleto.

Comment: Isso varia de banco para banco.

Comment: desculpa minha ignorância, @rray, sei que a pergunta pode aparentar incompleta... pra mim isso é o "simbolo" de concatenação entre colunas, não? Mas minha pergunta pra ti é: o que pode variar de banco pra banco? Oo. Isso pra mim sempre vai ser concatenação entre colunas.. rs

Comment: @MarllonNasser no SqlServer e no MySQL por exemplo a concatenação de colunas é diferente. No SqlServer vc concatena utilizando o + por exemplo

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No Oracle e no Postgres os dois pipes (`||`) são o operador de concatenação.

Já o MySQL por padrão não usa um operador mas uma função, [concat()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) entretanto é possível trocar ela pelos pipes alterado o valor da variável `sql_mode` para `PIPES_AS_CONCAT`

```
SELECT 'teste' || 'algo'
```

Retorna uma coluna concatenando os dois valores.

[Documentação - Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/operators003.htm)

[Documentação - Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html)

[Documentação - MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_pipes_as_concat)

Answer (score 10):

O que seu código está fazendo é é selecionar duas colunas da tabela `Trem`, a `xf0cdloc` e a `XN4CDEMP`, e está construindo uma coluna virtual que só existirá nessa consulta. Essa coluna virtual chama `LOCOMOTIVA` e seu conteúdo é a concatenação do conteúdo de `xf0cdloc` depois um traço (`'-'`) e em seguida já cola o conteúdo de `XN4CDEMP`.

O `||` é o operador de concatenação. Ele é definido na especificação do SQL padrão. Mas alguns sistemas de banco de dados que não o implementam, então esta sintaxe pode não funcionar dependendo de onde use. Por causa disto algumas pessoas recomendam usar a função [`CONCAT()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-concat-function.htm) quando deseja que o código seja portável para outros sistemas.

Em outros sistemas ou outras linguagens seria o equivalente a fazer isto:

```
Select
  xf0cdloc + '-' + XN4CDEMP AS LOCOMOTIVA,
From
  Trem
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/Concat.sql).

Answer (score 2):

Server Para Concaternar String, no Oracle é possivel concaternar string com number, entretanto no SQL SERVER é necessário converter number para string